# How to avoid/manage process/thread starvation?

Tags: ros, threads

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short version: how to keep one (cpu bound) node from starving all other nodes without explicit `sleep()`?

---

I have a system in which one node (in particular) is a cpu hog and also publishes a lot of messages. This node is a source node, with the rest of the nodes waiting and only acting on messages they receive (from the cpu hog, or other nodes).

What I'd like to do is give this source node a lower priority, so that it only gets the cpu if the other nodes are idle (or at least, not very busy). The idea is that the source will still publish ('as fast as possible'), but without getting in the way of the processing nodes.

AFAIK, `nice` should do this on Linux, and can be used as a [`launch-prefix`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) to run a node at a specific nice level, but it "doesn't seem to work" in my case. I've verified the nice level with `ps axl | grep -i nodename`, and it is at 19 (with `PRIO` at 39), but the other nodes (at `NI` 0 and `PRIO` 20) are still starved of cpu and are loosing many messsages (note that higher `PRIO` values are less likely to be given cpu time).

I'm wondering if `nice` is the proper way to achieve the described behaviour, or should I use something else?

PS: there is no `sleep(..)` anywhere in the source node, it's essentially an infinite 'busy' while. Sleeping 'solves' the described issue, but there is no explicit need for periodicity and also seems to incur overhead (ie less messages published than possible). For obvious reasons a request-reply (even if a pub-sub acknowledge) system is undesirable.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40128/how-to-avoid/manage-process/thread-starvation?/) by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-29

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-30**:
Does maybe a usleep(1); help?

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-30**:
Well 'yes': sleeping allows other processes/tasks to get some cpu time, but I'd like to avoid it, as it puts an (artificial) upper limit on the maximum nr of messages published, even if there are no other nodes using cpu. Thanks for your comment though.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-30**:
The usleep(1); hack shouldn't really be influencing the number of messages much as it is only one microsecond or better it gives up control to other processes for a very short time. If that works, it might be worth a try with no other processes running. Although I do remember using this only for inner process "nicing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can make your process explicitly relinquish its cpu time by calling `sched_yield`, defined in the header file `sched.h`. It just moves your process to the end of the scheduling queue for the corresponding priority.

I guess the reason why renicing the process doesn't have the expected effect is that the scheduler is only called after your thread's time is over, i.e. processes with a higher priority are called only after your thread either performs a syscall or the OS calls the scheduler through a timer interrupt. That's really just a guess though. Using `sched_yield` should work, even when you don't change the priority.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-30**:
Yes, I've tried that, but using `boost::thread::yield()` in the while loop. I need to do some more testing I guess. Yielding helps to a degree, but not as much as I'd like.